# CKEditor show block element HTML

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor version 4.5. I want to configure showing HTML blocks for content.
Please help me.

[image: Block element HTML]

Answer (score -1):

Please use the [Show Blocks plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/showblocks) in your CKEditor build and it should work. It comes by default in the full-featured preset of CKEditor, but you can also add it to your custom build by using [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).